# Can't access properties with angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to display properties from data but it doesn't work & i don't understand why. No error in the console.

My component:

```
export class BlogpostComponent implements OnInit {
blogpost$: Observable<BlogPost>;
id;
blogsId;

constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private blogpostService: BlogpostService) {}

getBlog(id) {
    this.id = id;
    id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    console.log('id', id);
    this.blogpost$ = this.blogpostService.getPost(id);
    console.log('blogpost', this.blogpost$);
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.getBlog(this.id);
    console.log('OBS', this.blogpost$);
}
```

my view:

```
<div>{{ blogpost$ | async | json }}</div>
<ng-container *ngIf="blogpost$ | async as bp; else loading">
  <div
  class="card text-white bg-secondary mb-3" 
  style="max-width: 18rem;"
  >
  <div class="card-header">{{ bp.content }}</div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Hello there</h5>
    <p class="card-text">
      Hello text
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
</ng-container>

<ng-template #loading>Loading post ...</ng-template>
```

my service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class BlogpostService {
  url = "http://localhost:3000";

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  getAllPosts(): Observable<BlogPost[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<BlogPost[]>(`${this.url}/allblogs`);
  }

  getPost(id): Observable<BlogPost> {
    return this.httpClient.get<BlogPost>(`${this.url}/blog/${id}`);
  }
}
```

this `<div>{{ blogpost$ | async | json }}</div>` print the json with all properties as it should.

But when i call properties in my view `{{ bp.content }}`, i've nothing displayed.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Where are you setting `bp` value?

Comment: do you have some errors in console ?

Comment: Can you post exactly what `<div>{{ blogpost$ | async | json }}</` prints please.

Comment: @viqas [ { "id": 1, "title": "Quel sera le temps demain", "subtitle": "A voir ...", "content": "Demain le temps sera probablement bon ..." } ]

Comment: @DarioN1none :/

Comment: there's your problem. `blogpost$` is being set to an array instead of an object, that's why it isn't displaying.

Comment: @Viqas but it is not ... blogpost$: Observable<BlogPost> not blogpost$: Observable<BlogPost[]>;

Comment: @LinebakeR Like Viqas said, could you post what `<div>{{ blogpost$ | async | json }}</div>` show please ?

Comment: it doesn't matter what you define the type as, that's only for compile time. You're setting it to an array at runtime. To prove my point, change `{{ bp.content }}` to `{{ bp[0].content }}`

Comment: @Viqas you right it works... but how can i change it to an object?

Comment: Your api method from `getPost` should be returning you an object, not an array/list.

Comment: thanks for you help, i check that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem seems to be that `blogPost$` is being set to an array of blog posts instead of an object, that's why `{{ bp.content }}` is not displaying anything.

Even though `BlogPost` is defined as an object instead of an array, at runtime, you can still assign an array to the variable which is what is happening here.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see where you've defined `bp`. So you should either define it or replace it with the defined one `blogpost`.

**Update**
After finding the definition as alias in the HTML I would try to do `bp?.content`.

Comment: It's an alias of `bolgpost$`. Look better in the .html : `<ng-container *ngIf="blogpost$ | async as bp; else loading">` :)

Comment: oh sorry, just found it. You may try `bp?.content`.

Comment: @LinebakeR This is exactly what I said ahah :) I was answering to the question, not asking :P